# Why does a human mind repeat the same mistakes?

Tags: brain, dopamine

Why does a person go on repeating the same mistakes again and again even if he does not want to? He knows that he is going to regret it later since he has already repeated this several times in the past. But still at that very moment, the urge to do the wrong overpowers every good or right thought coming in your head.

For example, you are studying and you feel like using your phone. 'Right' thoughts like "you should be studying, you'll regret it" come in your head but your urge of picking your phone up overpowers these thoughts. This is a very common example.

I have heard quite a few podcasts of Dr. Huberman on Dopamine and I know it is a hormone which gives you pleasure and pain, and is responsible for motivation and drive.

Comment: Welcome.  To be frank with you, this question is as broad as it is vague. Adding what you found so far during your own research efforts can greatly help to focus the question and clarify which direction you are heading with this question (what '*same mistakes*', what is *'wrong'* or '*good or right*'). In other words, you have to frame it into a Neuroscience and/or Psychology perspective. As of now, it is open wide for discussion, and this is not a discussion forum.

Comment: some pointing articles: [Why We Often Repeat the Same Mistakes - The Atlantic](https://www.theatlantic.com/science/archive/2016/02/why-mistakes-are-often-repeated/470778/ "Why We Often Repeat the Same Mistakes - The Atlantic") [WATCH: The Science Behind Why We Keep Making The Same Damn Mistakes](https://www.sciencealert.com/watch-this-is-the-cognitive-science-behind-why-we-repeat-mistakes "WATCH: The Science Behind Why We Keep Making The Same Damn Mistakes")

Comment: Are you talking about procrastination?  I'm doing that right now (I should be grant writing ;-) No but seriously, is that what you are after? And specifically, the use of ***social media and procrastination***?

Comment: @AliceD It is a part of it. Another eg; you cheat in one exam, you feel guilty but still unwantingly keep on cheating in other exams knowing that it's a mistake. Does it clear a bit?

Comment: Search for [procrastination](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/search?q=procrastination) on this forum, there are already lots of questions about it.  Feel free to edit the question to ask something more specific that has not been asked before.  There is also addiction, learning, cheating, attention deficit, and other examples that you can search for.